# Get ID of preceding image on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have this HTML code

```
<div> <img src="download1.jpeg" image-id="9a8ae555af5f"></div>
<div><h1><a href ="#">test</a></h1></div>
```

When a user clicks on the "test" link, i would like to navigate through the tree and fetch the "image-id" attribute of the image preceding the link

I have tried this but imageID returns undefined

```
function trackClick(event)
{
  let imageId = this.$('a').prev('img').attr('image-id');

console.log("imageId", imageId);
}

document.addEventListener('click', trackClick, true);
```

Any ideas on how i can make this work using js or css selectors?

thanks

Comment: try using class instead of id :  <div> <img src="download1.jpeg" class="9a8ae555af5f" image-id="9a8ae555af5f"></div> try class in html and use  -> attr(#9a8ae555af5f)  in js

Comment: Is `image-id` of your making ? There's an API for custum attributes that's valid: `data-*` it has terse syntax for methods: `<input data-id='X'>` get the value `document.querySelector('input').dataset.id` and to set it `document.querySelector('input').dataset.id = "Y"`

Answer (score 1):

This is jquery solution with prev() and parent() function:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).parent().parent().prev('div').find('img').attr('image-id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
  <img src="download1.jpeg" image-id="9a8ae555af5f">
</div>
<div>
  <h1>
    <a href ="#" id = 'test'>test</a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Vanilla JS, step by step:

```
function trackClick(event)
{
  let targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
     
  let closestDiv = targetElement.closest('div');

  let previousDiv = closestDiv.previousElementSibling;
  
  let insideImage = previousDiv.getElementsByTagName('img');
  // or
  // let insideImage = previousDiv.children;

  console.log(insideImage[0].getAttribute('src'));           
}

document.addEventListener('click', trackClick, true);
```

Comment: thanks @lluisma the code works fine only if the image is sitting in the div preceding the link. in my case there might be several divs between the image and the link. `code`      <div> <img src="download1.jpeg" image-id="9a8ae555af5f"></div><div >Additional div</div>
<div><h1><a href ="#">test</a></h1></div>          `code`     Is there a way to fetch the preceding image instead of searching via divs? thanks

Comment: You can loop on previous divs until yout find the one contains an image:
// Empty HTMLCollection
  let insideImage = document.getElementsByTagName("fake");
  
  while (insideImage.length==0) {
   let previousDiv = closestDiv .previousElementSibling;
   insideImage = previousDiv.getElementsByTagName('img');
    closestDiv  = previousDiv;
  }

Comment: thanks @Iluisma, does the insideImage = document.getElementsByTagName("fake");  replace  let insideImage = previousDiv.getElementsByTagName('img'); ? I have added the extra code but still not possible to navigate through the previous divs, in some scenarios, the code will return the first image on the page . you can find here https://jsfiddle.net/zcnemoa1/ my code and an example of an html structure i am trying to navigate

Comment: The 'fake' selector is my way to create and empty HTMLCollection (surely there's a better/more formal way). In your example, you forgot to close the last div tag. With my code, the anchor <a> can't be inside a div inside a div. I've rewrited your example here: https://jsfiddle.net/lluisma/hpkeyjsv/ .